DNS resolving differences between Windows 10 and Windows 11
Using the same DNS server, resolving the same address results in different response if the DNS query is from Windows 11 versus other machine.
All machines receives the same DHCP setting using the router as a DNS server, and sitting on the same home network with no segmentation.
This command: nslookup -d2 subaddress.mydomain.com.
On Windows 11 returns:
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.0.1

------------
SendRequest(), len 40
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  query, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        subaddress.mydomain.com, type = A, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer (96 bytes):
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 2,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        subaddress.mydomain.com, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  subaddress.mydomain.com
        type = CNAME, class = IN, dlen = 28
        canonical name = subdomain.dyndnsprovider.com
        ttl = 300 (5 mins)
    ->  subdomain.dyndnsprovider.com
        type = A, class = IN, dlen = 4
        internet address = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (my public ip address)
        ttl = 60 (1 min)

But from a Windows 10 or Windows Server 2019 returns:
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.0.1

------------
SendRequest(), len 40
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  query, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        subaddress.mydomain.com, type = A, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer (56 bytes):
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        subaddress.mydomain.com, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  subaddress.mydomain.com
        type = A, class = IN, dlen = 4
        internet address = 192.168.0.3
        ttl = 300 (5 mins)

Is there any known difference with DNS queries on Windows 11?
Nslookup is seemingly using the DNS server (as it states Address:  192.168.0.1), but the DNS server does not log the query from the Windows 11 machine, regardless of the IP setting. The other machines query is logged.
The only thing I can think of that Windows 11 doesn't like the classic, "unencrypted" DNS server, and try to act on its own using some predefined DNS server.
How can I debug it?

perhaps there's something in /windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts file?

This is not Windows – it is nslookup.exe, which deliberately does not use the Windows DNS query mechanism. Can you use Wireshark to prove that nslookup.exe is sending, or not sending, the DNS query packets through your ethernet interface? (If it is sending packets, be sure to also look at which destination MAC address it is sending them to. If it is not sending packets to 192.168.0.1 port 53, look for any other packets on ports 53 or 853 or 443 on all interfaces.)

Both Windows 10 and 11 resolve names using DNS in parallel with broadcast name resolution. Name resolution on your home network is not as deterministic as you may think. A simple packet capture on the 11 host will show where the results are from.

Thanks for the directions it seems that I found the culprit:

With wireshark I found out that all the DNS queries on the problematic machine go from 127.0.0.1:someport to 127.0.0.1:53
Using SysInternals TcpView I could identify that a service (dnscryptproxy.exe) is act as a local dns resolver (sitting on 127.0.0.1:53)

I have Cisco Secureclient installed (but not connected) and it contains a module called umbrella. That caused the problem.
Stopping/exiting the client won't stop the service.
After the service is manually stopped the DNS resolving is working again.
Originally I ruled out this client as an another machine in my network (with windows 10), using an older Secureclient (configured to the same endpoint) resolved the domain name correctly. I checked now that client does not have the umbrella module.
Surely I could have dismissed my Windows 11 suspicion if I had an another windows 11 machine in my network.
